# Centered div with fixed width, fixed position sidebars

Tags: css

I want to create a layout of 3 columns. The center has a fixed width (e.g. 500px). The sidebars need to have a fixed position, so that their content remains always visible. This content has to be floated close to the middle column.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dAg49/) is what I came up with so far. Unfortunately, I couldn't fix the sidebars. The code is replicated below.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="pixelLeft">
        <div id="pixelLeftContent">
            Column 1 has to be fixed, with liquid width.
            It's content needs to be floated to left;
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bannerCenter">
    </div>
    <div id="pixelRight">
        <div id="pixelRightContent">
            Column 2 has to be fixed, with liquid width.
            It's content needs to be floated to right;
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#bannerCenter {
    background:#ddd;
    width: 500px;
    float:left;
    height: 1000px;
}
#pixelLeft {
    background:#999;
    width: calc(50% - 250px);
    float:left;
}
#pixedLeftContent {
    width: 50%;
    float:right;
}
#pixelRight {
    background:#999;
    width: calc(50% - 250px);
    float:right;
}
#pixelRightContent {
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
}
#pixelLeft, #pixelRight {
    height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, i dont think css supports % and px together... it may solve your problem..

Modify Your css like this:

```
#pixelLeft{
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
    position: relative;

}
#pixelLeftContent{
     background:#999;
     float: right;
     margin-right: 250px;
}
```